# Satellite of Love- what inspired its name and design?

Tags: mst3k

With a handle like "Satellite of Love" and the fact the ship's shaped like a cartoon dog bone I keep thinking it's a dirty joke that slipped over my head- did the show's creators ever address these questions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The Design:

The shape was a reference to the famous bone-throwing scene from *2001:  A Space Odyssey*, [as MST3K creator Joel Hodgson explains](http://www.artofthetitle.com/title/mystery-science-theater-3000/):

> Trace got the unique bone shape of the Satellite of Love based on the moment in 2001: A Space Odyssey when the bone/tool from primitive man gets thrown up and turns into the spaceship — genius.

It was also chosen for plot purposes, [as Trace Beaulieau (one of the founders of MST3K) explains](http://www.mst3kinfo.com/satnews/brains/20q_tb.html):

> Q: You also made a considerable contribution to the art direction side of the show, including much of the work on the Satellite of Love models. What was your premise as you worked on them? **How did the "dog bone" shape come about?** Were you thinking in terms of how a real spaceship might look? Or were you just hoping to create something that looked neat?
>
> **A: The shape of the S.O.L. came about because the Demon Dogs that had attacked the ship in an early episode were attracted to it because it looked like a bone.** I had very little time to build the first one so I used foam core because it was light and easy to work with. I was influenced by Ron Cobb's design on ALIEN and the little round ship in FIRST MEN IN THE MOON. The models for the film gave me a chance to get more detailed, especially on the eight foot. Again they were made out of foam core with a lot of stuff glued to them. Basically I wanted them to look neat.

---

### The Name:

The inspiration for the name itself was the Lou Reed song.  [MST3K creator Joel Hodgson confirms this:](http://www.villagevoice.com/music/talking-mystery-science-theater-3000s-25th-anniversary-with-creator-joel-hodgson-6652238)

> Well, obviously Satellite of Love is from Lou Reed. And, I just thought the song had such a strange quality to it so I really wanted to drop a reference to Lou Reed, he launched so many ships musically. Also, Rocket Number 9, which was the motivated camera whenever you saw an establishing shot of the ship, was obviously a reference to Sun Ra.

[Another quote from Hodgson](http://www.artofthetitle.com/title/mystery-science-theater-3000/):

> And obviously, the term “Satellite of Love” is an homage to Lou Reed, who, to me, is the architect of punk rock.

> Satellite's gone up to the skies
>   Things like that drive me out of my mind
>   I watched it for a little while
>   I like to watch things on TV
>
> Satellite of love
>   (Bum, bum, bum) Satellite of love
>   (Bum, bum, bum) Satellite of love
>   Satellite of
>
> Satellite's gone way up to Mars
>   Soon it'll be filled with parkin' cars
>   I watched it for a little while
>   I love to watch things on TV
>
> Satellite of love
>   (Bum, bum, bum) Satellite of love
>   (Bum, bum, bum) Satellite of love
>   Satellite of
>
> I've been told that you've been bold
>   With Harry, Mark, and John
>   Monday and Tuesday, Wednesday through Thursday
>   With Harry, Mark, and John
>
> Satellite's gone up to the skies
>   Things like that drive me out of my mind
>   I watched it for a little while
>   I love to watch things on TV

In fact, [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_of_Love#Cultural_references):

> The song itself, with lyrics reflecting the characters ("Gypsy, Tom, and Crow" instead of "Harry, Mark, and John", for example), was sung at the end of all live shows featuring the cast.

[Lyrics to the MST3K version:](http://mst3k.wikia.com/wiki/Satellite_of_Love_(song))

> JOEL: Satellite's gone--up to the stars.
>   Things like that drive me out of my mind.
>   TOM: [in background]  Oooooo!
>   JOEL: We're only here a little while.
>   Are you like us?
>   TOM: [in background]  Ahh!
>   JOEL: [spoken] Do you like to watch things on TV?
>
> AUDIENCE: Yeah!
>
> TOM: Ah, ah, ah, ah. Bop.
>   CROW: Bop.
>   GYPSY: Bop.
>
> JOEL & TOM: Satellite of love.
>   TOM: Bop.
>   CROW: Bop.
>   GYPSY: Bop.
>
> JOEL & TOM: Satellite of love.
>   TOM: Bop.
>   CROW: Bop.
>   GYPSY: Bop.
>
> JOEL & TOM: Satellite of love.
>   Satellite of--
>   TOM: Love.
>
> JOEL: Satellite's gone--way up to Mars.
>   TOM: [in background] Ooo! Ahh!
>
> JOEL: [spoken] Hey, Frank. Take this one.
>
> FRANK: Uh, it seems like we're all gonna be parking cars.
>   Jack?
>
> JACK PERKINS: I watched it for a little while,
>   And for me--that is good TV!
>
> JOEL & TOM: Ah, ah, ah, ah.
>   TOM: Bop.
>   CROW: Bop.
>   GYPSY: Bop.
>
> JOEL & TOM: Satellite of love.
>   TOM: Bop.
>   CROW: Bop.
>   GYPSY: Bop.
>
> JOEL & TOM: Satellite of love.
>   TOM: Bop.
>   CROW: Bop.
>   GYPSY: Bop.
>
> JOEL & TOM: Satellite of love.
>   Satellite of--
>
> JOEL: [spoken] I've been told
>   That you feel bold
>   About Gypsy, Crow and Tom.
>   TOM: Ye-ho!
>
> JOEL: Monday, Tuesday,
>   JOEL & TOM: Wednesday, Thursday.
>   JOEL: Gypsy,  Crow and Tom.
>   TOM: Tom! Ye-ho! Ah!
>
> DR. FORRESTER: Finally, satellite's gone--up to the sky.
>   TOM: Du, du, du, du, du, du.
>   DR. FORRESTER: This time it'll blow your little mind.
>   TOM: Ah, ha.
>   GYPSY: Ah!
>
> DR. FORRESTER: I watched you for a little while,
>   And then I changed to "Charles in Charge."
>   JOEL & TOM: Ah, ah, ah.
>   TOM: Bop.
>   CROW: Bop.
>   GYPSY: Bop.
>
> JOEL, FRANK & TOM: Satellite of love.
>   TOM: Bop.
>   CROW: Bop.
>   GYPSY: Bop.
>
> JOEL, FRANK & TOM: Satellite of love.
>   TOM: Bop.
>   CROW: Bop.
>   GYPSY: Bop.
>
> JOEL, FRANK & TOM: Satellite of love.
>   Satellite of--
>
> TOM: [spoken] Okay, people, I want you to twink your fingers for those of us who can't! Twink! Come on now! I want you to sing with us, now. Sing with feeling; sing with heart; sing "Satellite of Love." Here we go.
>
> JOEL, FRANK & TOM: Satellite--of love.
>   GYPSY: Love!
>   TOM: Sing along now.
>
> JOEL, FRANK & TOM: Satellite--
>   GYPSY: Satellite!
>   JOEL, FRANK & TOM: --of love.
>
> JOEL, FRANK, T & C: Satellite--
>   GYPSY: Satellite!
>   JOEL, FRANK & TOM: --of love.
>
> TOM: Satellite--
>   --of love.

And from the [official MST3K FAQ](http://www.mst3kinfo.com/mstfaq/subtle.html):

> **Q: Where have I heard the phrase "satellite of love" before?**
>
> A: ..."Satellite of Love" is also the title of a Lou Reed song on his 1973 "Transformer" album. This song was sung by cast members at the close of every live MST performance. Also, in the chorus of the Def Leppard song "Rocket" (on the album "Hysteria"), one can also hear the phrase "satellite of love."